# Executing Functions using the Apps Script API in PHP script with service account of Google Cloud Platform

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps

I am referring to these documents
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/php
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute
for this implementation.

These document explains examples with Auth2.0. Since I am using GCP project for this implementation, i want to use service account of my GCP project for authorization.

I have used GCP service account to use SpreadSheet Apis and its works great.

After brain storming I have finally got answer that : service accounts are not allowed to access the Execution API.

I dont want to Auth method for this implementation and service account not supported by this API.

Question: Is there any other potential way to do this.

Comment: What about trying to run the script via an [API request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#api_request_examples) with the proper API Client Library. The client should be authenticated in order to perform the request successfully. The Client Libraries support [several methods](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_overview) for making authenticated calls to the Google APIs. Maybe you'll find something that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script via an [API request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#api_request_examples) with the proper API Client Library. The client should be authenticated in order to perform the request successfully. The Client Libraries support [several methods](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_overview) for making authenticated calls to the Google APIs.